# Error in Jenkins-Xray result import task using TestNG XML

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng, jira-xray

I am trying to import the test results using Xray from Jenkins and using the TestNG XML as a source file. When its trying to import the results from Jenkins it was failing with the below error

```
Import Cucumber features Task started...
##########################################################
#### Importing the execution results to Xray  ####
##########################################################
Starting to import results from testng-results.xml
ERROR: Step ‘Xray: Results Import Task’ failed: Unable to confirm Result of the upload..... Upload Failed! Status:500 Response:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source issue    at com.xpandit.raven.service.impl.RavenIssueLinkManagerImpl.a(Unknown Source)   at com.xpandit.raven.service.impl.RavenIssueLinkManagerImpl.createIssueLink(Unknown Source) at com.xpandit.raven.service.executionresult.impl.ExecutionResultImportServiceImpl.a(Unknown Source)    at com.xpandit.raven.rest.internal.b.a.a(Unknown Source)    at com.xpandit.raven.rest.internal.b.a.d(Unknown Source)    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5928.invoke(Unknown Source)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$ResponseOutInvoker$1.invoke(DispatchProviderHelper.java:192)   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$1.intercept(DispatchProviderHelper.java:83)    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DefaultMethodInvocation.invoke(DefaultMethodInvocation.java:53)   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.expand.interceptor.ExpandInterceptor.intercept(ExpandInterceptor.java:41)  at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DefaultMethodInvocation.invoke(DefaultMethodInvocation.java:53)   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper.invokeMethodWithInterceptors(DispatchProviderHelper.java:110)  at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(DispatchProviderHelper.java:190)  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)  at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:159)  at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:829)    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.doFilter(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:69)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilterInternal(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:22)  at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilter(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:34)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:32) at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.UniversalAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(UniversalAnalyticsFilter.java:75)    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:33)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21) at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:32)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:55)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:80)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:51)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:36)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MobileAppRequestFilter.doFilter(MobileAppRequestFilter.java:36)   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:92) at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:78)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:46) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.pagebuilder.PageBuilderFilter.doFilter(PageBuilderFilter.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.doFilter(CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.java:55)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MauEventFilter.doFilter(MauEventFilter.java:49)   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraSecurityFilter.java:66) at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:242) at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:64)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:94) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148)   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:77) at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:67)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:37)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.johnson.JiraJohnson503Filter.doFilter(JiraJohnson503Filter.java:79)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)  at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.java:30) at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.JiraAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(JiraAnalyticsFilter.java:40)  at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:33)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21) at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.LocationCleanerFilter.doFilter(LocationCleanerFilter.java:36)   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)  at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:31)   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:39)  at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:39)   at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.doFilter(MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.java:36)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.MetricsCollectorFilter.doFilter(MetricsCollectorFilter.java:25) at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74)   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraFirstFilter.doFilter(JiraFirstFilter.java:57) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:115)    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(StuckThreadDetectionValve.java:206)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure below in Jenkins>Manage Jenkins>Configure System

Xray Configuration

Hosting: CLOUD (Must be CLOUD, or else import will fail)
Credentials: Username (Client D), Password (Client Secret)

How to find Client ID and Client Secret?

1. Open JIRA
2. Go to Apps>Manage Apps
3. Click API Keys
4. Click Create API Key
5. Once generated, copy Client ID and Client Secret and paste as Username and Password for Xray Configuration in Jenkins